# getColor function does not return color leaflet?

Tags: angular, leaflet

I try to add a legend to my Map so I use this code:

```html
    function getColour(d) {
      switch (d) { 
        case 'IPMSAN': return '#00FF00';
        case 'PARK': return '#000000';
        ;
      }
    };
      
    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
    
    legend.onAdd = function (map) {
      var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
       let faultstatus = ['IPMSAN', 'PARK'];
        
      // loop through the status values and generate a label with a coloured square for each value
      for (var i = 0; i < faultstatus.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
          '<i class="circle" style="background:' + getColour(faultstatus[i]) + '"></i> ' + (faultstatus[i] ? faultstatus[i] + '<br>' : '+');
      }
      return div;
    };
    legend.addTo(map);
```

As you can see, I set the color as follows but In my map i can't see an color only 'faultstatus ' ,Any help or guidance on how I can make it shown ?
and this is the CSS:

```html
.legend {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #555;
  }
  .legend i {
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  }
  .legend .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  }
```

Comment: Works fine with the provided code: https://plnkr.co/edit/rN7nWAfLfXvRvXsNsq5H?p=preview